# Mysql one to many relation data retrival

Tags: mysql

I have tables like

**tbl_biodata:**

```
id     : int           value=>1
name   : varchar(50)        value => mike
...
```

**tbl_biodata_education**

first row---

```
id         : int    value=>1
biodata_id : foreignkey to tbl_biodata.id   value => 1
level      : varchar(50)    value => bachelor
year       : int(4)     value => 2006
```

second row---

```
id         : int    value=>2
biodata_id : foreignkey to tbl_biodata.id   value => 1
level      : varchar(50)    value => masters
year       : int(4)     value => 2010
```

I have to export data such that the biodata won't repeat more than one time and all the 
repeated education from tbl_biodata_education lists as bachelor 2006, masters 2010

The final table would be:

```
id
name    => mike
education   =>  bachelor 2006, masters 2010
```

***Solution*** from [simon-at-mso-net](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1213554/simon-at-mso-net)

```
SELECT
        b.id,
        b.name,
        GROUP_CONCAT(be.education) AS education

FROM tbl_biodata b

LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        biodata_id,
        CONCAT(level,' ',year) AS education
    FROM tbl_biodata_education
) be
ON b.id = be.biodata_id
GROUP BY b.id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GROUP_CONCAT is your friend for getting the entries you need as a list, with 1 list per `tbl_biodata record`.  I opted to suggest a subquery to get the data from `tbl_biodata_education` simply so that the `education` field could be `CONCAT`ed more cleanly before being `GROUP_CONCAT`ed in the outer query

```
SELECT
    b.id,
    b.name,
    GROUP_CONCAT(be.education) AS education

FROM tbl_biodata b

LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        biodata_id,
        CONCAT(level,' ',year) AS education
    FROM tbl_biodata_education
) be

on b.id = be.biodata_id

GROUP BY b.id
```

Comment: it gives error:
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'GROUP BY b.id LIMIT